# Change Ant Design button disabled boolean based on setState

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, antd

I have this 3 [buttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Rode.jpg) here. So at first, the **Continue** button is disabled, because I want the user to click the **Click Here** button then only the **Continue** button can be clicked, where the disabled is then set to `false`.
Here's what I've tried:

```js
let [clicked, setClicked] = useState(false); 
let clickedLink = () => setClicked(() => true)

 {
    clicked ? <Button href={links[0]} target="_blank" style={buttonStyle2}>Continue</Button> : <Button href={links[0]} target="_blank" style={buttonStyle2} disabled>Continue</Button>
 }
```

But then even after I clicked on the link, the button is still `disabled` because the `clicked` state is not updated. How do I constantly check the `clicked` state as what I did only check the first time when the components are loaded.

Comment: Changing the `state` causes a re-render: https://felixgerschau.com/react-rerender-components/#when-does-react-re-render also, you could reduce the code for rendering your button by following the JSX example found at: https://sebhastian.com/react-disable-button/

Comment: @ConnorTJ I see.. I get it now, thank you!